# How can I solve a nonlinear fractional order integro-differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

[image]

How do I solve the nonlinear fractional order integro-differential equation shown above in Mathematica?

Comment: I've implemented Hubers method for this type of stuff (many years ago). You should find it relatively straight forward https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00607-009-0074-3

Comment: can you give me your email id sir?